# Listener on entire Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, events, listener

I am working on a Java Swing application.  Is it possible in any way I can listen to entire application UI?

I want track any changes in a UI should trigger a event so that I can do my required processing.  Listener should not be widget/component specific.

Comment: Please read the tag pop-ups carefully before slapping them on a post.  The [tag:windows] tag does not mean what you apparently thought it meant.

Comment: What kind of event do you want to track ?

Comment: If the GUI had all text components, it would probably be possible to make a common `DocumentListener` that could be added to all of them.  What types of controls are in the app.?

Comment: You could take a look at [`Toolkit#addAWTEventListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener(java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long))

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. But here I am trying to listen on the swing application which is already developed. I dont have a source of that application to modify it. I want that whenever that application screens undergoes any changes(clicking of button, display of table in any frame or dialog etc) I should be able to trace those changes.